# Node.js HTTP request return headers without body?

Tags: node.js, http, request, axios, media

Is there a way for an HTTP request in Node.js to return only the response headers and not the body? Specifically with the Axios library?

The reason I want to do this is because I want to check if a user has provided a URL that hosts a media file without having to download the entire - potentially huge - file itself.

For example, if I visit https://media3.giphy.com/media/3oEduIOpXCpGxagbQY/200w_s.gif, then I can see that `content-type: image/gif` is included in the response headers. For my application, I would only need to check that the `content-type` header indicates a media file. Downloading the entire file would be overkill.

So how can I configure Axios to do this? Or, if not with Axios, how to do this from within a Node.js application in general?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You're looking to do a *HEAD* request, research that with axios as a keyword and your find many examples on the interwebberoos.

Comment: Yes, of course, it slipped my mind to do a simple HEAD request. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios
  .head('https://media3.giphy.com/media/3oEduIOpXCpGxagbQY/200w_s.gif')
  .then(res => console.log(res.headers['content-type']));
```

Use the `head` method and grab the headers you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and for showing how it's done with Axios specifically. Much appreciated